# What is the sixth derivative of $f(x) = \cos^2(x)$?

Tags: calculus

I am able to find the sixth derivative of $\cos(x^2)$ by simply replacing the $x$ in the Taylor series for $\cos(x)$ with $x^2$ but beyond simple substitutions, I am struggling...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean $$f(x)=\cos(x^2)$$ of $$f(x)=(\cos(x))^2$$?

Comment: **Hint.** The derivative of $f(x)^2$ is $2\cdot f(x)\cdot f'(x)$ using the chain rule. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I mean cos^2(x)

Comment: Ohhhh yes thanks for the hint, I got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos 2x$.

$\displaystyle f^{(6)}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(2)^6(-\cos 2x)=-32\cos2x$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to differentiate $6$ times, you can just brute force it. Indeed
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\cos^2x\\
f'(x)&=-2\cos x\sin x=-\sin(2x)\\
f''(x)&=-2\cos(2x)\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$
and so on. The rest is just remembering the trig derivatives and using the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
Linearise first:
$$\cos^2x=\frac12(1+\cos 2x),$$
and differentiate $\cos 2x$ six times, remembering that
$$(\cos u)'=\cos\Bigl(u+\frac\pi2\Bigr)u'=\cos\Bigl(2x+\frac\pi2\Bigr)\cdot 2.$$